# Is there a way to print the data inside the private constructor in C#

Tags: c#, .net

In a recent interview I was asked how can we print the data inside the private constructor of the class,consider the following code

```
public class Geeks { 


    private Geeks() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Private Constructor"); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: So whats' your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `public static` method which creates an instace of your class:

```
public class Geeks
{
    private Geeks() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Private Constructor"); 
    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        new Geeks();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call the private constructor like this, but this is not thread safe. you can make it thread safe (Reference: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)

```
public class Geeks
{
    public static Geeks geeks;
    private Geeks()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Private Constructor");
    }
    public void CallerMethod()
    {

    }
    public static Geeks GetInstance()
    {
        if(geeks == null)
        {
            geeks = new Geeks();
        }
        return geeks;
    }
}

Geeks geeks = Geeks.GetInstance();
geeks.CallerMethod();
```

Comment: I don't think the OP asked about singletons, or did he?